# Write records per partition in spark data frame to a xml file

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin, spark-csv, apache-spark-xml

I have to do the records count in a file per partition in spark data frame and then I have to write output to XML file.

Here is my data frame.

```
dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("DataPartition","StatementTypeCode")
  .format("csv")
  .option("nullValue", "")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("codec", "gzip")
  .save("s3://trfsdisu/SPARK/FinancialLineItem/output")
```

Now I have to count the number of records in each file in each partition and then write output to an XML file.

This is how I am trying to do it.

```
val count =dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.groupBy("DataPartition","StatementTypeCode").count

  count.write.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rootTag", "items")
  .option("rowTag", "item")
  .save("s3://trfsdisu/SPARK/FinancialLineItem/Descr")
```

I am able to print total no of records per partition and print that but when i m trying to create xml file i am getting below error .

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.xml. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

I am using  `Spark 2.2.0, Zeppelin 0.7.2`

So do I have to import `com.databricks.spark.xml` this, but why because in case of csv file if I am  not importing `com.databricks.spark.csv`.

Also, can I use cache `dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull` because I will be using it twice to write its data and then count its  partitions records and then write in the xml file?

And I added this dependency

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-xml_2.10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-xml_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And restarted interpreter. Then I got the following error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext_2(SparkInterpreter.java:391)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:380)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:146)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question

so i added below dependency in zepplin

```
Scala 2.11

groupId: com.databricks
artifactId: spark-xml_2.11
version: 0.4.1
```

Added below in the zepplin

```
com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:0.4.1
```

And then i was able to create files .